# Ruby error when updating Compass on Mac OS 10.11.3

Tags: ruby, macos, compass-sass

Whenever I follow the instructions on the compass-style.org website I keep getting this error in the terminal:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
MARS:Enrollment MARS$ gem install compass
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot things like this and was wondering if anyone had encountered this issue before and how they resolved it.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with SSL certificates. Have you been able to install any other ruby gems?

Comment: @luke actually I haven't needed to install any other gems so not sure which ones I could try out to see if this is an isolated issue. Let me see if I can find a gem that I do a test install and get back to you. But it's interesting that you mention that the SSL cert could've expired in which case I didn't realize that npm wouldn't install a module that had an expired SSL. Thank you.